# working with lisp functions

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a function that returns a list of atoms in a list,lets say i have a list which has both atoms and a list in it and when I run the function it should return a list of atoms inside..

For example:

```
(func '(2 34 5 (12) 7 (A B C) +))
 -> (2 34 7 +)
```

And I want to try if the arguments inside the result are true such that when I run:

```
(ATOM ( (func '(2 34 5 (12) 7 (A B C) +)) )
->T
```

Any ideas on how I can go about it? Books or references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard CL functions,

```
[3]> (remove-if-not #'atom '(1 2 (12) +))
(1 2 +)

[6]> (every #'atom (remove-if-not #'atom '(1 2 (12) +)))
T
```

If you want to write them yourself, you can fuse the `#'atom` in and make two specialized functions, say `remove-atoms` and `every-is-atom`. But "atom" is a name of a [built-in function `atom`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_atom.htm).

One way to write the first is

```
(defun remove-atoms (xs &aux (ys (list 1)))
  (let ((p ys))
    (dolist (x xs (cdr ys))
      (if (atom x) (setf (cdr p) (list x) p (cdr p))))))
```

This builds the result list in a top-down manner using destructive update, which doesn't violate the spirit of functional programming *here* because it is used locally, as an implementation technique. This can be seen as a Common-LISP–specific translation of the general functional [*tail-recursive-modulo-cons*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) code from the other answer.

And the second function:

```
(defun every-is-atom (xs)
  (dolist (x xs T)
    (if (not (atom x)) 
      (return-from every-is-atom NIL))))
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want a function that only returns the atomic values that exist in the list passed as an argument?

Like this?

```
(defun func (lst)
  (cond 
    ((null lst) '()) 
    ((atom (first lst)) 
     (cons (first lst) (func (rest lst)))) 
    (t (func (rest lst)))))
```

Not for Common lisp specifically, but still a good read in my opinion: [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)